# Return all values for a path of keys in a json when target key in list and non list

Tags: python, json

Lets say I have this json :

```
   json_data = json.loads("""
{


    "result":{         
        "statistics": [
                        {
                            "name": "A1",
                            "year": 1994,
                            "award": "Y1"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "X1",
                            "year": 1990,
                            "award": "Y55"
                        }
                    ],

         "isTrue": "yes"           
            }

}""")
```

Is there a way to return for a path of keys all the values found on the request?

Note that the json can change and have another structure, but the paths will always be specific for the json. So for example something like this won't work because the keys are not the same every time, hardcoding is not an option :

```
json_root = json_data['result]['statistics']
json_result = [something['name'] for something in json_root]
```

Expected result

> For example:
>
> ```
> Path = 'result/statistics/name'
>
> The result could be a dict like this : {'name':['A1', 'A2']}
>
> Path2 = 'result/isTrue'
>
> The result : {'isTrue: ['Yes']}
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like that with a function that recursively reads the data and follows the nodes that correspond to the given path. If we arrive at a list we just follow the path within all elements of that list:

```
import json

def getAllValues(data, path):
    """Get all values from data that match the given path.
    """

    # If the key is not in the dictionary, no element could be found
    if path[0] not in data:
        return []
    else:
        # We arrived at the end of the path, add whatever is there
        if len(path) == 1:
            return [data[path[0]]]
        else:
            # If we have a list, we want to add the values for all elements in the list
            if type(data[path[0]]) is list:
                out = []
                for elem in data[path[0]]:
                    out += getAllValues(elem, path[1:])
                return out
            # If its not a list, we can just coninue on
            else:
                return getAllValues(data[path[0]], path[1:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = {
        "result": {
            "statistics": [
                {
                    "name": "A1",
                    "year": 1994,
                    "award": "Y1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "X1",
                    "year": 1990,
                    "award": "Y55"
                }
            ],
            "isTrue": "yes"
        }
    }

    path = "result/statistics/name"
    print(getAllValues(data, path.split("/")))
```

I get the following output:

```
['A1', 'X1']
```

Comment: Thats because the path there should be `results/isTrue`. `results/statistics/isTrue` does not exist